# How can I tell which workbook triggered an event?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a BeforeClose event in a workbook, however if the user closes the workbook when it is not the active workbook, e.g. from the taskbar, the script executes on the wrong workbook.

Is there a way to tell which workbook triggered the event and reference that workbook rather than ActiveWorkbook?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'   Replaces default Save message box with custom one
'   that includes request stats, warnings, and errors.
    If Not ActiveWorkbook.Saved Then
        UF_Stats.Show
        If Not GlobalVariables.bAllowClose Then Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `ThisWorkbook`instead of `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple solution! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook` – Vincent G